# How to create DataTable with included entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core with Linq to get entities from the database, and I want to get some entities with included data and make DataTable from it.

Request from `DbContext` looks like this:

```
_context.dbset.Include(x => x.RelatedEntity);
```

Sometimes it can be

```
_context.dbset
        .Include(x => x.RelatedEntity)
        .ThenInclude(c => c.RelatedEntity);
```

But I have no idea how I can do this..

Comment: Do you *really* want to load results as an ADO.NET DataTable? EF Core is used to load objects *instead* of DataTables. What are you trying to do? Why do you want a DataTable?

Comment: In ADO.NET a DataTable contains rows with the results of a single query. If you want multiple DataTables with relations between them you need [a DataSet with relations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-datarelations)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I try create simple way to export data with relations to excel document, maybe you can give me some advice or links, which I will analyse

Comment: Excel has no relations, it's a flat structure. Columns lookups aren't relations. Nor does it need a DataTable. You can use a library like EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML and many more to create a real `xlsx` file and even load it with a single call, eg `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(listOfObjects);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need export all data with relations into one spreadsheet

Comment: Again, spreadsheets have no relations. PowerPivot data models do, but you can't create these programmatically. What are you trying to create? What do you mean by "relations"? How would that look in an Excel sheet?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am already use EPPlus but it specific task. need export all like SQL output with copies the same data but include other new values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it must looks like i was used the Left Join

Comment: Which is a flat result. No nesting, no relations. Flatten your results before generating the Excel file. Instead of using `Include` to load related entities, use a `Select` that returns all the columns you want as properties

Comment: Another option is to just execute the SQL query you want eg using [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) or ADO.NET. EPPlus 5+ has a `LoadFromDataReader` method. `LoadFromDataTable` is available in all versions, but `LoadFromDataReader` avoids keeping a copy in memory